# How to debug chrome devtools panel extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to write Chrome DevTools extension, but I am having some troubles to debug it.

How can I inspect my panel html and debug it's javascript?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you detach the Dev Tools (icon next to `x` in the top right corner) in a separate window, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> while Dev Tools window is focused, you will invoke the Dev Tools for the Dev Tools window.

As far as I am aware, it's not possible for a docked configuration.

Comment: Has anybody been having any issues when reloading an extension? It seems like I have to reload an extension several times in order for its code to show up in the dev tools window again.

Comment: It should be noted that the dev tools will need to be closed and reopened in order to refresh the changes

Answer (score 3):

Found an easy way, just right-click in the Devtools panel, of your extension, and in the popup click on "inspect". it will open another Devtools for the entire Devtools with a focus on your extension panel HTML.

No need to detach the main Devtools.

Comment: YES SIR THAT'S CORRECT!

Answer (score 2):

To me it works with detaching the DevTools and hit CTRL+SHIFT+i (Windows).

Comment: To explain the existence of this answer: my original answer had an error in the key combination (Alt instead of Shift). This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>OPTION</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

Version 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) (arm64) (Apple m1 silicon)