# Debugging Chrome extension sidebar panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension which adds a [SidebarPanel](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ExtensionSidebarPane). 
I add it in devtools.js:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
    "Guardian",
    function (sidebar) {
        sidebar.setPage('extension/sidebar.html')
    });
```

sidebar.html includes the required JS - sidebar.js.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
</head>
...
<body style="min-height: 200px">
...
</html>
```

**Problem:**
In the Devtools debug views I can't see the sidebar.js file anywhere - hence I can't debug it. Following the [technique listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661243/how-to-debug-chrome-devtools-panel-extension) I can bring up the background.js and devtools.js - No sidebar.js though.

Comment: I think [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) should work (it can be used on the same computer and same browser instance).

Answer (score 0):

To debug the sidebar.js file in your Chrome extension, follow these steps:

- go to chrome://extensions/ in your address bar.
- Find your extension in the list and click on the "**Inspect views**" link under it.
- A new window will open, displaying the standalone DevTools for your extension.
- In the standalone DevTools, you can access different panels similar to regular Chrome DevTools, such as Console, Elements, Sources, and Network. This will allow you to debug your extension effectively.

Here's the screenshot to show where to find the links:

- screenshot: [Inspect views Entry Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3BJc.png)
- screenshot: [Inspect view Lists for service worker and side_panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmWBQ.png)