# How to create a chrome extension with Angular 2 RC1

Tags: google-chrome-extension, angular

I am trying to create a DevTools Page extension in chrome with angular 2 RC1 but i found some problems to do it. In previous versions of angular (beta-7) i don't have this type of problems.

I think the problems they are related with some cross origin request (XMLHttpRequest) in the Zone.js file or because there exist some violations of content / restrictions of chrome extensions.

Someone had a problem of this kind?

For angular 2 app i use to test the panel [the tour of heroes tutorial of angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). And the configuration of the remaining files is more or less the following:

*(manifest.json)*

```
...
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",   
"minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
"devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html",
```

*(devtools.js)*

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Heroes Panel","icon.png","index.html",null);
```

PS: I am newbie in this new world of angular. :shy:
Thanks for the help possible!

EDITED. These are the mistakes that i got in the console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-G0mTaF6bWvyc4n9GAJfTdnuzxv4B+t1WU0aL2FBX94A='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: For angular2 beta 17 see here working fine https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2_typescript_ChromeExtension

Comment: Error messages would probably be helpful in tracing the issues. You can [debug Dev Tools panels while they are detached](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27661701/934239).

Comment: @Xan Thanks. I gonna edit the post with errors.

Comment: Thanks @PardeepJain for your suggestion. I will gonna try.

Comment: I think you need to wait until offline template compiler is available. It is supposed to solve the CSP problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is chrome extension content security policy. You can see the doc https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script

if you have inline script in your html

```
<script>// js code</script>
```

change to

```
<script src="xxx.js"></script>
```