# How to disable Dev Tools popup to reload externally changed css?

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

I get this annoying dialog when my SCSS is compiled by sass ruby gem.

How do I disable it?

[image]

Comment: This is [hardcoded](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/workspace/UISourceCode.js?l=268&rcl=cd31831bb240ce19d3e3af6f2b95f8ad11c96e5c). You can probably disable it in the current devtools instance by [invoking devtools-for-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27661701) and running `confirm = ()=>true`. Or patch resources.pak file.

Comment: Thanks. What's funny is that it doesn't appear all the time, just 30% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this simply by removing the folder which contains the compiled assets from Chrome's workspaces. I never quite saw the point of having compiled assets in there anyway, and it gets rid of the dialog.

[image: Removing folder from Chrome Devtools workspace]