# Using jQuery in Chrome devtools panel

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a Chrome extension that adds a devtools panel. I'd like to use jQuery within the panel to build and modify the contents (of the panel, not the page), rather than using plain JavaScript.

Within **devtools.html** I've added references to a local jQuery file and the devtools.js:

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
```

When looking in the network tab I can see that both files were loaded correctly (and devtools.js is executed without problems.)

However, window.jQuery (or $) is never made available in devtools.js, or from the console.

I've also tried adding this in manifest.json without any success:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js", "jquery-2.2.4.min.js"]
}
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't I be able to use jQuery here?

Comment: Pages (devtools panel included) in chrome extensions are like separate/different tabs in the browser, meaning each one has its own DOM and execution context. You need to add jQuery to the panel's html, not to the "master" devtools_page. Also, when using console for tests pay attention to the context dropdown selector on the top of the console toolbar. In case of debugging a devtools panel it's trickier: you need to invoke [devtools-for-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27661701).

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this question from Google, as I did, this is how to add jQuery into the DevTools console:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Reference/Source:

[Include jQuery in the JavaScript Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console/7474386#7474386)